# Split string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have a string whose format like "945-20-4:397-3:320" or "945-20-41-90-4:397-3:320" . I need to split it bases upon 1st ":" and last "-" from left of 1st ":".

Like for "945-20-4:397-3:320" I need 2 part like '945-20' & '4:397-3:320'.

For "945-20-41-90-4:37-3:320-1:232", 2 part will be like '945-20-41-90' and '4:37-3:320-1:232'.

How to spilt it?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Show us the Regex expression you tried and what it's doing wrong.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé, yes. I 1st got index of 1st ':' , then split the string by that index, Not used the 1st part of string to get index of last '-' of 1st string and again, used that index to split the string in 2 part.

Comment: `yourString.LastIndexOf('-', 0, yourString.IndexOf(':'));` will give you the location of the last `-` before the first `:` though you'll want to verify that `IndexOf` doesn't return -1 before using it in `LastIndexOf`.

Comment: @user1926138 Show that code in the question and tell us in what way it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go 3:D

```
void Main()
{
    Splitter.Print(Splitter.GetParts("945-20-4:397-3:320"));
    Splitter.Print(Splitter.GetParts("945-20-41-90-4:397-3:320"));
}

unsafe static class Splitter
{
    public static ValueTuple<string, string> GetParts(string whole)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        fixed (char* parts = whole)
        {
            char* lastDashPosition = null;
            var terminus = parts + whole.Length;
            for (var x = parts; x < terminus; ++x)
            {
                switch (*x)
                {
                    case ':':
                        builder.Remove((int)(lastDashPosition  - parts), 
                            (int)(x - lastDashPosition));
                        return ValueTuple.Create(builder.ToString(), 
                            whole.Substring((int)(lastDashPosition + 1 - parts)));
                    case '-':
                        lastDashPosition = x;
                        break;
                }

                builder.Append(*x);
            }

            throw new InvalidOperationException("String not in expected format.");
        }
    }

    public static void Print(ValueTuple<string, string> v) 
    {
        Debug.Print("Token 1: " + v.Item1);
        Debug.Print("Token 2: " + v.Item2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there's an SIMD implementation for this as well xD

Comment: Oh and you may want to wrap calls to GetParts in a try catch (AccessViolationException).